# What are the available java API to backup mysql database

Tags: java, mysql, backup

Are there any API for java to backup mysql databases?

Comment: This link might help you a bit http://sandeepsharma11.blogspot.com/2011/02/mysql-database-backup.html

Comment: @YankiTwizzy interesting stuff. And, lolwut _`System.out.print("I am here yaaar");`_ is ... exceptional exception handling :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use any Java API (through JDBC/JConnector) to backup a MySQL database. But unless there is a specific reason to do, I strongly suggest that you use MySQL specific tools (e.g. mysqldump) to create your backups.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Runtime.exec(String)` to run `mysqldump` command

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you are trying build a tool which would do this. I would suggest you to reconsider it as there are readily available tool from mysql which does this job for you. If you are looking for automating the backup process, then I would recommend using the [unix script](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/mysql-backup-script.html).